# Apache CXF: sending a byte array

Tags: java, arrays, rest, cxf

We are sending a byte array to a REST API we do not control.
The REST API requires the byte array to be sent as the body.

The code is as follows:

```
    String path = "/dokumente/angebote/{angebotsId}/unterlagen/{dokumentId}";
    WebTarget target = createWebTarget().path(path).resolveTemplate("angebotsId", angebotsId).resolveTemplate("dokumentId", documentType);

    try (ResponseHandler handler = new ResponseHandler(
            target.request(document.getMimeType()).header("Content-Type", document.getMimeType())
                    .post(Entity.entity(MY_BYTE_ARRAY))) {

        Response response = handler.getResponse();

    ...
    }
```

This has worked well so far, we have been using JBoss and RestEasy. We have now migrated our application to OpenLiberty, which means that Apache CXF will be used as JAX-RS implementation.

And since the migration, the implementation does not work anymore. We found out that if we use a wrapper class like that:

```
 MyWrapper myByteArrayWrapper = new MyWrapper();
 myByteArrayWrapper.setData(MY_BYTE_ARRAY)); 
 .post(Entity.entity(myByteArrayWrapper))
```

then Apache CXF will successfully transfer the byte array, but this does not comply to the API definition of the service we are calling.

Has anybody succeeded in getting a byte[] upload running with Apache CXF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that OLP (in contrast to JBoss) used chunked transfer. The server that we called did not support that. Chunked transfer was now enabled on the other server, and now everything works.